# Is the ɴᴜʟ character forbidden in filenames for Git repositories?

Tags: git, security, buffer-overflow, rugged, null-character

Without considering any implementation behaviour or host ᴏꜱ, are there by design, characters which aren't allowed in file or directory names?

I’m especially interested *(considering Git is sometimes used as front-end)* if the ᴀꜱᴄɪɪ ɴᴜʟ character is allowed.
If this isn’t allowed, can the attempt to create such file with rugged lead to remote code execution ?

Comment: **No ! This isn’t too broad !** if there is a disallowed character there is a **definite answer !** *(yes it is)*. **Otherwise, please explain how to insert a filename containing a ɴᴜʟ byte in a ɢɪᴛ repository !**

Comment: Your title asked whether NUL is allowed; the body of the question asks whether some characters are *not* allowed. Since an existing answer says "Yes", meaning that some characters are forbidden, I've rephrased the title accordingly. (I also replaced the small capitals with ordinary uppercase letters; non-ASCII characters might be difficult to read on some systems.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  The index and tree objects both impose limitations due to their design:

1. A `NUL` cannot be in a path name.  git uses null terminated strings to store filenames internally, both [in the index](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/src/index.c#L2231) and in [tree objects](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/src/tree.c#L401).
2. A `/` cannot be in a filename, as it is the path separator in the index.

There are additional limitations imposed by Git clients, which are not part of the design of the data file formats:

3. A path component cannot be named `.git`.
4. A path component may not be named `.` or `..`, to prevent you from escaping your working directory.
5. If `core.protectHFS` is set, then when all [zero-width Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) are removed from a path component, the remainder may not be `.git`.
6. If `core.protectNTFS` is set, then a path component may not be `GIT~1`, `.git\` or `.git` followed by trailing spaces or dots.

And no, you cannot create those with libgit2 either, because *it* also uses null terminated strings to store paths.  It seems unlikely that there's a buffer overrun potential here (if anything, you would expect a buffer underrun).

Comment: Wrong ! A`/`can be used in [git repositories](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline). If you [clone this](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline), the directory containing the`/`will be converted to 2 different directories. Doing a`git update`on that locally cloned repo will split the directory on most ᴏꜱ.

Comment: Are you talking about `lib/html`?  That's a `lib` directory with an `html` directory within it. GitHub is collapsing that in their web UI to be nice - that's why the `lib/` is grey.

Comment: Do you mean this is automatic ? I’m sorry in that case…

Comment: @user2284570: It's not automatic. It's a github (a website) feature. Not a git feature. If you want such a feature in your software you have to implement it yourself like github did.

Comment: @EdwardThomson : At least, I see many 500 errors with servers using libgit2 instead of 422 or 403 when I use other characters like & or >.

Comment: Then you should file a bug with them so they can investigate.

Comment: @EdwardThomson : `git uses null terminated strings to store filenames internally`I’m curious to look at other things. Would it be possible to get some documentations about binary data structures used by git objects ? *(with the objective of manually changing them of course)*

Comment: If you haven't seen them yet, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals and https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation/technical are the places to start.  After that, the source for your favorite git implementation (git, libgit2, dulwich, jgit) is probably going to be best.

Comment: @EdwardThomson : Does the path restriction *(`.`and`..`in names)* is enforced by database design ?

Comment: @EdwardThomson : Ok I tested it and it isn’t. As the question is only asking about database and not any implementation behaviour, please update your question.

Comment: @user2284570 You didn't mention the database in your question.  More importantly, you didn't mention *which* one.  The index and tree objects both contain paths, and do so very differently and thus with different limitations.  I'll point those out in my answer.

Comment: @EdwardThomson : All kind of objects.

Comment: That's why I gave you both.